# Integer variable no longer usable after forall construct

Tags: variables, integer, fortran

I have an integer variable that is declared at the head of my subroutine. After I've used it as a control variable inside a `forall` construct, I can no longer use it as the control variable of a `do` loop. The compiler (Intel, v. 12.0.3) complains

```
xyz.f90(1210): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [I]
            do i=1,sp_basis%num_dim
---------------^
xyz.f90(1210): error #6063: An INTEGER or REAL data type is required in this context.   [I]
        do i=1,sp_basis%num_dim
```

I have tried to write a small example to replicate this behaviour (and compiled the file with the same compiler options as the actual problematic one, apart from `-c`), but this compiled & worked nicely, so below is my (slightly shortened) problematic code (`implicit none` applies to the entire module this code belongs to):

```
subroutine xyz(stuff)

   use data, only: ppm, npeaks

   ! some declarations
   integer :: i ! ...

   associate(sp_basis => public_spectra%basis(counter))

      spots = npeaks * np

      allocate(ref_curves(spots,npeaks,sp_basis%num_dim), stat=stat)
      if (stat.ne.0) then
         ! ...
      end if

      forall (i=1:max_dim) uppers(i) = ubound(sp_int%int,i)
      forall (i=1:max_dim) lowers(i) = lbound(sp_int%int,i)
      forall (i=1:npeaks,j=1:sp_basis%num_dim) peak_pos_hertz(j,i) = ppm_to_hertz(ppm(permutation(j),i), sp_axes(j))

      do peak_considered=1,npeaks
         do pos=(peak_considered-1)*np+1,peak_considered*np
            do i=1,sp_basis%num_dim   ! <-- COMPLAINT
```

If I change `i` to a name that was not used as a `forall` construct's control variable everything works. Also, this is the second time I've run into this problem.

This is how the compilation is done (xyz.f90 is one of many files that make up the entire program):

```
ifort -c -g -C -check noarg_temp_created -traceback -warn -warn nodeclarations -nogen-interface xyz.f90
```

Does any of you know what the problem might be?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: I have just tried to reproduce the problem you are seeing with a simple test program but cannot. From reading *Fortran 95/2003 explained*, by Metcalf *et al* it seems that what you are trying to do is perfectly valid. Can you try posting a self contained minimal example program which reproduces the problem?

Comment: Have you tried asking this question in the Intel Support Forums? From what I hear, they are quite helpful, and even though it usually isn't the first thing to think of, it may just be a bug in the compiler.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a compiler 'issue' to me.  If you are paying for your Intel compiler, use their tech support, it's pretty good.  If not, do as @eriktous suggests.

Comment: @Chris I have tried constructing a minimal example, but so far I've failed to come up with one which gave me this same error.

Comment: @eriktous I have not yet tried this, but it seems like a good suggestion. I'll post my question there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all those interested, it's a bug in the Intel compiler. [Here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=105016&p=1) you can read more about it. Also it sounds like this bug will be fixed in a compiler version that is to be released some time in 2012.